# View Document Online from PHP server

Tags: php, download, attachment

I am currently tasked to make a website that allows a personnel of people to select possible candidates for a job.

From here, the candidate will upload their resume online to the PHP server. After which, the candidate will view the resume for review to see whether is the candidate suits for the job. I would like to know how is it possible to allow them to download the document from the server and/or view the documents online, probably in another browser page.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Depends on the document types. At least there are javascript libraries for some well-known document types. For ``pdf`` for example take a look at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how is it possible to allow them to download the document from the server and/or view the documents online, probably in another browser page.

1. After a file was moved from the temporary upload folder to your "uploads" folder, you are able to generate a download link to the file.
2. The file can be view "online", when the viewer opens the file in a new browser tab (by right-clicking the download link, then open in new tab) or you set `target="_blank"` on the link.
3. Most modern browsers have PDF support. I would only suggest to utilize a document viewer on server side, if the download links must be protected and the user-group is rather small, because this doesn't scale well.